# How to prevent Fiddler/Firebug from showing my HTTP requests?

Tags: firebug, fiddler, http-trace

I do not want my traffic to be logged by Fiddler/Firebug or any such tool.

How can I achieve this? Is HTTPS the only answer?

I got this idea when I was googling something but my Firebug was on and it showed access denied.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Image is at : http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wi7dq8&s=8#.VCZa2_mSyCY

Comment: What's the reason you want to prevent devtools from reading the communication with the server?

Comment: Hey Sebastian.I do not want to prevent reading, I jst do not want it to expose.  I do not want to expose my api calls. As REST exposes the urls, headers everything. You can say in production I want to achieve it. Also, as mentioned when I was on google, facebook firebug simply said Access Denied. Is it possible for me???

Comment: Asking again, what's the reason why you want to avoid exposing that info? Do you want to avoid hackers from seeing how your network requests/responses are structured? Where exactly did you see that *Access Denied* message? Can you post a screenshot (or a link to one as you don't have enough reputation yet)?

Comment: Sebastian Zartner: I am not sure why are you asking this again and again. Its simply my requirement. If you are aware of please share.

Comment: I am asking because your question is not very specific and lacks some important information. Therefore I also could just give a general answer. To get more precise answers you should read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Not sure, why this attitude, I am asking a question because I have some proofs about it. If people are not able to understand it , then I am providing more inputs to it.

Its not my fault that my things will be kept on hold. Also, I am not able to add images to elaborate on my problem until I have  10 reputation.

Comment: As of http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user you're allowed to post at least two links. So please edit your question, add a link to a screenshot at an image service and provide a test case with steps to reproduce your problem and what you'd want to see (i.e. which information you do not want to be exposed).

Comment: Sebastian Zartner image url is added. PFA
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wi7dq8&s=8#.VCZa2_mSyCY

Comment: The screenshot you posted says that Firebug Lite cannot be opened for the Google Chrome new tab page, because extensions don't have the priviledge to run scripts within browser-internal pages for security reasons. Besides this note that Firebug Lite doesn't have access to any network info. So this is unrelated to any network requests, i.e. has actually *nothing* to do with what you wrote earlier. Additionally note that [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) is *not* [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to suppress client side tools to inspect the HTTP communication between the browser and the server. Even HTTPS doesn't help here, as browser integrated devtools have access to the decrypted information.

> Also, as mentioned when I was on google, facebook firebug simply said
>   Access Denied.

As you didn't post any info about where you saw that message, I can't tell you the reason why you saw it. Though the server needs to expose certain info to the browser, so it can interpret the request correctly. And there is no means from the server side to forbid the client to read that data - even not pages like Google or facebook as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image: facebook request info shown in Firebug]

Comment: Thanks, But I can not add images here. please share your emailId so that I can post it there.